# How files permissions are changed after enabling Kerberos (Cloudera Hadoop)?

Tags: hadoop, authentication, permissions, kerberos, cloudera

After one enables kerberos authentication on cloudera's hadoop - he cannot login and work with local users, only ldap/active directory users apply. Which is great.

But what happens to all those files and folders on hdfs who had their permissions determined by the "old" users and groups?

How those permissions are affected, assuming new user names are not synced with the old ones? (would it matter if they were synced?)

Comment: If you have privileges to set "user" and "group" for a HDFS file, then you can set about *anything*. Even if that "user" and that "group" don't exist in your AD domain - which means nobody will have access to the file, except privileged accounts (e.g. `hdfs`).

Comment: So you will have to create a Kerberos TGT as `hdfs` then run a series of HDFS commands in the line of  `hdfs dfs -chown -R ad_usr1:ad_group1 /user/usr1` and `hdfs dfs -chown -R ad_svcA:ad_groupA /projects/projectA` to reset file & directory ownerships. Plus a series of `-chmod` and/or `-setfacl` commands to set access privileges; beware of some syntax bugs in "chmod" and a nasty design bug in "setfacl" (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6962) so take time to test the results.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what you're saying: after enabling Kerberos, files and folders will be left inaccessible for hadoop users up until the hadoop admin will manually configure user and group permissions for each file and folder?

Comment: It depends: let's assume that all "local" users had primary group `wtf` and a UMASK that would generate default file privileges with `g=rw`; and let's assume that your Linux-to-AD mapping rules still force a primary group of `wtf` for all users (with sthg like `override_gid = 666` in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` where 666 is the ID of group `wtf`). Then the existing privileges will still apply. Because of a cunning migration plan :-)

Comment: But generally speaking, you will have to "migrate" the owner/group/privileges of existing files & directories by yourself. From HDFS point of view, enabling the Linux-to-AD mapping is just like creating a bunch of new users.

Comment: Understood. Thank you, @SamsonScharfrichter